# Setting up an AIS Reciver

Tags: pi-2, usb

I want to set up an AIS receiver on my pi. Any ideas how this can be done. I have a generic RTL-SDR USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

You will need software to receive and decode AIS signals. Reception is handled by a package called `rtl-sdr` which can be installed using `apt-get`. For decoding I would recommend [xDeco](http://xdeco.org) which provides builds for the RPi.

You may want to take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/rtl-sdr-tutorial-cheap-ais-ship-tracking/) to see how it all fits together and what kind of antenna you will need. I suggest you try to receive some signals on a laptop first, so that you will only have to deal with RPi-specific problems when trying this out on an RPi.